# How to get Google indexing AngularJS Web apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, google-crawlers

I have an single page application built using AngularJS. All requests gets served up the index.html, and from there, Angular takes on the routing and queries a set of API endpoints to get the data to display.

The title and SEO metadata and description for the site is obtained the same way. The catch is that the API endpoint is on a different domain so the SPA is actually doing cross origin requests to get the data.

Everything works fine from a users point of view. However, when google crawls the site, it does not pick up any metadata or title, instead, it just shows the angular tags.

Looking through the site logs, I can see requests with Google bot only doing an OPTIONS request and not following with the actual GET.

How can I get google to index the page properly?

Here is a screenshot of what it is looking like:

[image: See first search results]

The site is https://www.careercontroller.com

Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: I know I can get this to work by generating static HTML from the server using PhantomJS or something, but I'm looking to get Google to index it properly since according to them, they crawl AngularJS apps just fine.

I have actually got this to work before, except the requests are not cross-domain, so could that be the problem?

Comment: this seems like a good solution but I have to say I've never had to deal with this issue.
https://prerender.io/

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue that is solved by products like [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/)

Comment: Yeah, I knew there are a host of server side tech that handles this perfectly. But my question was more on how to leverage the new Google search which parses javascript. I'm wondering if the CORS request is the culprit